# Update in sqlite database from another activity?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have made a class `MyDBHandler.java` which contains a user defined function to update data like update `mytable(String email,String table_name)`. I want to update the data in a table by passing email and table_name from another activity. How can I do it.

Currently I m writing this is `MyActivity.java` but it is not working.

> MyDBHandler db;
>
> db=new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
>
> db.update(current_email,"table");

Comment: do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this: [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)
Insanely easy way to work with Android Databases.